# regex just have 2 items

Tags: regex

here is my web list

```
mywebsite/
mywebsite/myweb.html
mywebsite/children1
mywebsite/clidrend2
mywebsite/clidrens3
mywebsite/clidrend4
mywebsite/parent1/S2
mywebsite/parent1/S3
mywebsite/parent1/S4
```

how do I just have

```
 mywebsite/myweb.html
 mywebsite/
```

and ignore the others.

here is my regex

```
mywebsite/|mywebsite/myweb.html
```

Comment: Are you saying you want exactly two separate matches, regardless of the content you're matching? Or perhaps you only want (1) something that has exactly one slash, and that slash is at the end, and (2) something that ends with `.html`?

Comment: @KyleStrand yes would like to only have that two separate matches

Comment: What I mean is, what exactly is the distinguishing quality of these lines that you need to extract?

Comment: @KyleStrand get this sorted! thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry, what about sorting?

Comment: `^mywebsite\/myweb\.html|mywebsite\/$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it :-) thanks everyone

```
^mywebsite\/myweb\.html|mywebsite\/$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, I could be more precise if you show us the regex you are actually using.

```
(WhateverYouAreUsing){2}
```

`(...)` is a group and `{...}` is a quantifier, it will take exactly two of the matches you are looking for. {1,2} will take at least one and at maximum two, in case there is only one and you still want to get a match.

Comment: This will be a single multi-line match, though, which I'm guessing won't be that useful to the OP.

Comment: The original (undisclosed) regex was performing that multiline match

Comment: No, I don't think it was.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want as a result?

```
mywebsite(/m.*|/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put some parentheses in your regex and escape the `.`:

```
(mywebsite/)|(mywebsite/myweb\.html)
```

Alternatively, for something a little more general:

```
(\w+/)|(\w+/\w+\.html)
```